# Does DBIx::Class do unions?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

I haven't found a way to do unions with [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class) other than using a view and writing out the SQL manually.  This seems strange to me.  I feel like there should be some way to union two ResultSets without a lot of extra work because set addition and subtraction are such a core part of SQL.  Is there an easier way to do unions?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[DBIx::Class::Helper::ResultSet::SetOperations](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Helper::ResultSet::SetOperations)

```
my $rs1 = $rs->search({ foo => 'bar' });  
my $rs2 = $rs->search({ baz => 'biff' });  
for ($rs1->union($rs2)->all) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (without having to load more modules) I did something like this:

```
$db->resultset("Foo")->search({ -or => [ 
                                        'me.id' => { -in => $result_set_a },
                                        'me.id' => { -in => $result_set_b } 
                                       ]
                              },
                              undef);
```